# Background color turns black after OnPress, when displayed on top of FlatList

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Very strange behavior, I am using a `FlatList`, and on top of it there are 2 floating buttons (`TouchableOpacity`) (absolute position) and when they are pressed, their background color turns black.
This happens only on IOS.

[image]
[image]

Code:

**Render**

```
let content = (
  <CollapsableNavList
    onListScroll={this.showOrHideFilterButtons}
    showFilterButtonsOnScroll={this.showOrHideFilterButtons}
    style={styles.list}
    isHorizontal={false}
    dataModel={this.props.isFetching ? this.props.whileFetchingDisplayedResults : this.props.dataModel}
    isFetching={false}
    onRowSelect={this._onRowSelect}
    didScrollWithOffset={this.didScrollWithOffset}
    renderRowContent={this.renderRowContent}
    keyExtractor={(item) => {
      if (this.props.isFetching) {
        return item
      }
      const property = item
      return property.propertyId
    }}
  >
    {header}
  </CollapsableNavList>
)

return (
  <View style={[styles.container, styles.relative]}>
    <View style={styles.filterBtnBlock}>
      <AdditionalSearchParamsButton

        title='Map'
        iconName='map'
        onPress={this.onMapPress}
      />
    </View>
    {content}
  </View>
)


export default class AdditionalSearchParamsButton extends Component {
  // Prop type warnings
  static propTypes = {
    iconName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  render () {
    const { iconName, title, onPress } = this.props
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress} underlayColor={Colors.clear}>
          <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
            <McIcon
              name={iconName}
              style={styles.additionalPropsIcon}
          />
            <Text style={styles.additionalPropsText}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 50,
    width: 150,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  innerContainer: {
    height: 36,
    width: 126,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: Colors.snow,
    borderRadius: 18,
    elevation: 2,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  additionalPropsBtn: {
    height: 36,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: Colors.snow
  },
  additionalPropsText: {
    ...Fonts.style.bigTitle,
    color: Colors.blue,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  additionalPropsIcon: {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: Colors.blue
  }
})
```

What I've tried:

-Setting underlays color to clear, with no success.

-Adding different layers under, no success.

-This only happens when displayed on a list, happens with `ListView` too.

Answer (score 25):

Please use `TouchableOpacity`  instead of `TouchableHighlight`

`TouchableHighlight` Highlight the background when you click

Answer (score 24):

Try to add this: `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='none' />`

As per [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight#underlaycolor), this will change the color in the background that appears while active.

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves I don't think it needs to be an "excessively lengthy" description

Comment: @Rambatino Anyone who chooses to use this would likely need to either search for documentation about what this actually does or just blindly use it, which probably isn't the best idea. It's always a good idea to provide a link or description for context, as per Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 16):

try this in your TouchableOpacity props

```
underlayColor="#ffffff00"
```

Comment: anw, what color is that?

Comment: it's an invisible white color coded in rgba Hex, the first 6 digits define the color and the last two digits are the opacity, so any rgba color that ends with 00 like #fe123400 or #00000000 or #44556600... will have the same effects.

Comment: Gotta love [not having to worry about Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa) with React Native.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it using activeOpacity with background color

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} backgroundColor="#FFF"></TouchableOpacity>
```

You can use own backgroundColor

Comment: Or use `activeOpacity={0.5}` to give the user feedback for their selection as is standard, at least on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap `View` with `<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#fff">`